# CSS printed images are sized down

Tags: css, printing

I have large images and they are scaled down to page width when printing

```
<img style="width:1300px" ... />
```

How can I avoid the downscaling? I want them cutted at the border

Comment: I think this is printer setting instead of css.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Tivie answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365235/css-to-specify-full-page-width-at-printing): 
You can try to use the @page css rule. For example:

```css
@page { 
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but images are scaled down if width is to big